# JOptionPane display message

Tags: java, joptionpane

I have question about JOptionPane.
I was given an assignment to do the summation of odd number and even number.
My profesor want us to diplay the "my name, the summation of odd and even number" in one JOptionPane box output. The dialog box are not allowed to prompt user to enter number.

i only know how to display my name on the dialog box.
here is what i write.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

//class name
public class Loops
{
    //main method begin the execution of Java application
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
            //intialize the integer variable
        int sumOdd;
        int sumEven;
        int oddNumber;
        int evenNumber;

        sumOdd = 0;
        sumEven = 0;
        oddNumber = 1;
        evenNumber = 2;

        //create a conditional statement for integer odd number
        while ( oddNumber <=25 )    
        {
      sumOdd += oddNumber;
      oddNumber +=2;
        }   

        System.out.printf ("The sum of odd number is %d\n", sumOdd);    
        //create a conditional statement for integer even number

        while ( evenNumber <= 50 )
        {
      sumEven += evenNumber; 
      evenNumber +=2;
        }

        System.out.printf ("The sum of even number is %d", sumEven); 

        String message = "Written by BlaBla";

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }
}
```

before i wrote

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "The sum of odd number is %d", The sum of even number i %d", oddNumber, evenNumber );

and i also try another combination but it wont work

any idea how to do it?

Thank you so much in advanced for helping me out.

Comment: Just use this line to show numbers in JOptionPane. `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"The sum of odd numbers is "+Integer.toString(sum),"Title",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);`

Answer (score 1):

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

//class name

public class Loops {

```
//main method begin the execution of Java application
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //intialize the integer variable
    int sumOdd;
    int sumEven;
    int oddNumber;
    int evenNumber;

    sumOdd = 0;
    sumEven = 0;
    oddNumber = 1;
    evenNumber = 2;

    //create a conditional statement for integer odd number
    while (oddNumber <= 25) {
        sumOdd += oddNumber;
        oddNumber += 2;
    }

    String str = "The sum of odd number is =" + sumOdd;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str);
    while (evenNumber <= 50) {
        sumEven += evenNumber;
        evenNumber += 2;
    }

     str = "The sum of even number is =" + sumEven;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str);
    String message = "Written by BlaBla";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks Gauri Shankar, the code works. But i am not sure if this is what my professor want. It does display the sum of odd and even number on dialog box but its not being display together at the same time. My professor wants "the name, the sum of odd, the sum of even" three of this shows up a the same time, which is in 1 dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, 
   String.format("The sum of odd number is %d, The sum of even number i %d", 
       oddNumber, evenNumber ));
```

Good luck!

Comment: thank for you helping, apparently i got error when i try your code.

Comment: I can't help you without more information. What error you got?

Comment: i figured it out. so my professor want me to display 1.my name 2.sum of odd number 3. sum of eve number on 1 dialog box, which mean 3 of it should appear together, not one at a time. so this is how i write to get 3 of those appear together

Comment: String message = String.format( "Written by Andy Djie%nThe sum of odd number is %d%nThe sum of even number is %d", sumOdd, sumEven );

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, message );